# What is the meaning of noun "stable" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in a chapter named "Poets and Pancakes" which was:

> The make- up department of the Gemini Studios was in the upstairs of a building that was believed to have been Robert Clive's **stables**.

According to Merriam Webster dictionaries "stable" means - a group of people (such as athletes, writers, or performers) under one management. But that would then mean that "Robert Clive's stables" means his group of people.... But that doesn't seem to fit here because building is being talked about here.

Comment: You've cited an *extended / figurative* definition. Derived from the underlying *literal*  sense, which (as usual in dictionaries) is the ***first*** [noun definition in Collins:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stable) ***a building in which horses are kept***. Pretty obvious really, given that your cited text specifically says it's talking about a ***building***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand being confused between different noun definitions, but in this case it's the original, literal, physical definition - a building (or a part of a building) for horses (or occasionally other animals). The building was, in the past, a building that Robert Clive had that was intended for keeping horses, or at least that part was.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the wrong definition of "[stable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stable)":

> **stable** (noun) = a building in which horses or cattle are kept:
>
> - The horses in the stable have plenty of straw.